# modify validate function to accept variable

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a function (validate) which validates for correct email format on the front end first (to avoid most junk). At the moment it validates a single field and works fine. I tried modifying it to validate any field with class of "email" since there are several email fields on the same page. The second function (validateAny) works partially, it validates and shows the error message but does not add/remove the error class to the elements like it does in the first (validate) function. What am I missing here? Also, I'd like it not to validate the field if it is empty, then I'd like the check to be on the submit button instead. Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2wd6wh6/)

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function validate(){
  //$("#wrong-email-mess-create-process").text("");
  var email = $("#new-usr-name").val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $("#new-usr-name").removeClass('error');
    $("#new-usr-name").prev().removeClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeOut('fast');
    //$("#wrong-email-mess-create-process").text(email + " is valid :)");
  } else {
    $("#new-usr-name").addClass('error');
    $("#new-usr-name").prev().addClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeIn('fast');
    //$("#wrong-email-mess-create-process").text(email + " is not valid :(");
  }
  return false;
}

$("#new-usr-name").bind("blur", validate);



function validateAny(efield){
  var email = $(efield).val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $(efield).removeClass('error');
    $(efield).prev().removeClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeOut('fast');
  } else {
    $(efield).addClass('error');
    $(efield).prev().addClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeIn('fast');
  }
  return false;
}

$('.email').blur(function(){
    if( this.value ) {
    validateAny(this.id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its because you pass the id instead of the field in the blur event.

```
$('.email').blur(function(){
    if( this.value ) {
    validateAny(this);
  }
});
```

Or in your validateAny you need to add the id selector and then continue using the jquery object selected throughout the remainder of the function:

```
var $field = $('#' + efield);
var email = $field.val();
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2wd6wh6/2/

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you're passing the id to the function, but jQuery needs the '#' identifier to know that you want to use the id of an element. Try this:

```
function validateAny(efield){
  efield = '#' + efield;
  var email = $(efield).val();
  if (validateEmail(email)) {
    $(efield).removeClass('error');
    $(efield).prev().removeClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeOut('fast');
  } else {
    $(efield).addClass('error');
    $(efield).prev().addClass('error');
    $(".error-mess").fadeIn('fast');
  }
  return false;
}
```